# Spring-xd - Error when trying to stream data with "Twittersearch"

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

I created a stream that writes tweets into a file by this spring xd code:

```
stream create --name javatweets --definition "twittersearch --query=java --consumerKey=<my_key>
--consumerSecret=<my_secret> | file" --deploy
```

Unfortunately, I gets the following error messages:

```
WARN DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - 
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'org.springframework.integration.x.twitter.TwitterSearchChannelAdapter#0' defined in class path   resource [config/twittersearch.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'twitterTemplate' while setting  constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'twitterTemplate' defined in class path resource [config/twittersearch.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TwitterTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden
```

Answer (score 0):

> HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden

Your credentials (`consumerKey` and/or `consumerSecret`) are incorrect.